# JS button click (inside form) does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that have a button inside. That Button shall not submit the form. It shall trigger a JS-Funktion.

The Button:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.onlynumbers').keypress(function (e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode    
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode).match(/[^0-9]/g))    
      return false;
  }); 

  $("#weiter").click(function(event) {
   if(parseInt("#wortanzahl".value) > 0){
      $("#wk").attr("disabled", false);
      alert ("Test");
    } 
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  ...
  <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="weiter">Aktualisieren</button>
  ...
</form>
```

When I cklick on the Button. Nothing happend. What can it be?

Comment: Check browser's console, if there is any error

Comment: Pretty sure, that a button has no value, so parsing an int from that will not evaluate to something > 0... Try the alert or a console.log without the if condition there, so you see, if the event is executed

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen, and *why*?  Why specifically do you expect `parseInt(this.value) > 0` to be true?

Answer (score 1):

Any buttons in a form do a submit by default,
you just have to change

```HTML
 <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="weiter">Aktualisieren</button>
```

by

```HTML
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="weiter">Aktualisieren</button>
```

Comment: OK, very good hint. I editet it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition inside your click handler will never evaluate to true. Remove it and your alert will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.onlynumbers').keypress(function (e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode    
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode).match(/[^0-9]/g))    
      return false;
  }); 

  $("#weiter").click(function(event) {
      $("#wk").attr("disabled", false);
      alert ("Test");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  ...
  <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="weiter">Aktualisieren</button>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: OK, if I delete the "If", it work. But I need the If-Condition inside this Click.

Comment: @ChristianTürling What value are you trying to check? Is it a value from inside the form?

Comment: There was an error in the if(parseInt-Thing. I edit it know in the code below. I want to check if a input field has an value.

Comment: @ChristianTürling if you want to keep your code.. `if(parseInt("#wortanzahl".value) > 0){` is incorrect syntax.. first of all, a jQuery selector has to start with a dollar, so it would be $('#wortanzahl') and close the bracket afterwards... second, the method is .val() for jQuery.. so it would be `if(parseInt($('#wortanzahl').val()) > 0){`, which should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is likely what you want based on the incomplete information you have given:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#wortenForm").on("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); // stop submission
      const val = parseInt($("#wortanzahl").val());
      $("#wk").attr("disabled", val < 0); // no need to use an if on a boolean
      alert("Test");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="wortenForm">
  <input type="number" class="onlynumbers" />
  <input type="number" id="wortanzahl" />
  <button id="wk" disabled>WK</button>
  <button type="submit " class="btn btn-success mt-3 " id="weiter ">Aktualisieren</button>
  ...
</form>
```